# Cannot paint gradient with TexturePaint

Tags: texture-painting

So I'm just baffled how weird the texture paint is in Blender, it's the most non intuitive about the software Ive yet encountered. I almost take offence in feeling this stupid for not figuring this stuff out, coming from Photoshop and similar.

I chose Gradient under Colour Picker, paint and there's only one colour.
I try the Line from Stroke Method instead of Space, obviously I assume the line I paint should be gradient, no. I try repeat, I try clamp, I try swap the gradient colours, I try change strength. bla bla bla.
What possibly more should I even have to fiddle with to make it work? It's preposterous. That's all there should be to it! Ive looked around in the other options, theres few of them but none seem to make a difference in any way.

I have no problem painting "normally".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the default values of the brush settings which are unlucky chosen for the mouse users. (I had to [consult the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.93/sculpt_paint/texture_paint/tool_settings/brush_settings.html?highlight=gradient) to get it to work.)

If you have a mouse (no pressure sensitivity) then you need to increase the value for *Gradient Spacing* (which is 0 by default) and set *Gradient Mapping* to *Clamp* (or *Repeat*).

[image: paint with gradients]

Comment: thank you for assisting me with settings. After reading under clamp and gradient in the manual you linked I would not have connected the dots myself. 

The manual made me interested in Color Ramp Widgets HSL/HSV too.